# Polly WaitAndRetry with final exception does nothing

Tags: c#, vb.net, polly

I execute calls to an external service that is not very stable, and thus throws WebExceptions.
I want to retry a few times and after the last attempt I want to throw the last error received.

This is my attempt with [Polly (v6.1.1)](http://www.thepollyproject.org/):

```
public static Policy WaitAndRetryPolicy<T>(short nrOfRetryAttempts = 5) where T : Exception
{
    var waitAndRetry = Policy
        .Handle<T>()
        .WaitAndRetry(nrOfRetryAttempts, retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)));

    var fallbackForLastError = Policy
        .Handle<T>()
        .Fallback(
            fallbackAction: () => { },
            onFallback: (ex) => { throw ex; });

    return Policy.Wrap(fallbackForLastError, waitAndRetry);
}
```

Caller, legacy VB.Net:

```
Dim retryPolicy = Policies.WaitAndRetryPolicy(Of WebException)()
Dim theResult = retryPolicy.
    ExecuteAndCapture(Function()
                          Return aProxy.GetSomething(a, b)
                      End Function).Result
```

When I run the code as depicted above, *theResult* stays null and it seems like the service is not called.
If I just use the WaitAndRetryPolicy without the *Fallback* function, the service is called and the retry mechanism works as expected (without throwing the exception of course).

How can I achieve my goal, without having to check *PolicyResult.FinalException* in the caller code?

Comment: What is the goal of the `FallbackPolicy`? That particular formulation will probably add nothing - it just rethrows the exception that was thrown on to it.  Omitting that particular formulation, should have exactly the same effect.  To have the last exception rethrown rather than captured into `PolicyResult.FinalException`, simply use `Execute(...)` rather than `ExecuteAndCapture(...)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have Polly rethrow any final exception, rather than capture it into `PolicyResult.FinalException`, simply execute the policy with the `.Execute(...)` or `.ExecuteAsync(...)` overloads, rather than `.ExecuteAndCapture(...)` or `.ExecuteAndCaptureAsync(...)`

Comment: No, it's that easy! First article I read led me to the wrong path. Execute does exactly what you describe, and what I need, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know about the last exception but i have implemented a very similar behaviour with Retry and CircuitBreakerException(with Wrapping). So you can try 3 times and throw a circuitbreakerexception after 2 failures. Then you are able to react on the last exception.

```
Policy
.Handle<SomeExceptionType>()
.CircuitBreaker(2, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(x));
```